# Interoperability between Weblogic 10.3.1 and Oracle BPM 10.3.1

Tags: oracle, migration, weblogic-10.x, business-process-management, ora-17004

Im migrating an ALBPM 6.5 running on a WLS 10.0 to an Oracle BPM 10.3.1 running on WLS 10.3.1

I got some problems with the Oracle driver because the old driver (weblogic.jdbcx.oracle.OracleDataSource) was definitely removed from the server and is not longer supported. Instead I used the thin driver (oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource), the database migration was executed succesfully but after that, when I try to deploy the engine ear in WebLogic I got exceptions asociated to the driver:

```
[     (cont)     ] Main: Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "engineStartup" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/albpmServices/albpm_engine".                                  
[     (cont)     ] Main: fuego.directory.DirectoryRuntimeException: Exception [java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type].                                                                                                      
[     (cont)     ] Main:        at fuego.directory.DirectoryRuntimeException.wrapException(DirectoryRuntimeException.java:85)                                                                                                    
[     (cont)     ] Main:        at fuego.directory.provider.jdbc.oracle.OraclePersistenceManager.mapSQLException(OraclePersistenceManager.java:145)                                                                              
[     (cont)     ] Main:        at fuego.directory.provider.jdbc.datadirect.oracle.DataDirectOraclePersistenceManager.mapSQLException(DataDirectOraclePersistenceManager.java:51)                                                
[     (cont)     ] Main:        at fuego.directory.provider.jdbc.JDBCServiceAccessor.mapSQLException(JDBCServiceAccessor.java:78)                                                                                                
[     (cont)     ] Main:        at fuego.directory.provider.jdbc.JDBCObjectPropertiesAccessor.fetchAllDirectoryProperties(JDBCObjectPropertiesAccessor.java:442)                                                                 
[     (cont)     ] Main:        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I was looking around for a solution but all is pointing to use the old driver, I think isn't a good practice to force the server to use this driver after Oracle remove it completely.
Any suggestions or similar experiences??

Answer (score 0):

Do a database trace to see what query it is trying to execute in the `fetchAllDirectoryProperties` call that is generating the `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type` error.  That should point out what table/column is giving you the trouble and should make it easier to track down potential driver or upgrade issues.

Also, in the document below on page 5/6 it mentions that when using the thin driver you must set the property defaultNChar=true:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/bpm/bpm10gr3technicalarticles/OracleBPMClusteringTips.pdf

*Oracle BPM supports multi lingual capabilities. All schemas are prepared to 
store double byte code to ensure data integrity regardless of the location and locale 
where OBPM is used. When using the Oracle Internal JDBC Drivers (OEM from Oracle BPM 10gR3 Clustering Configuration Tips 
DataDirect), everything is automatically prepared. However, when using the Oracle 
Thin JDBC Driver, it is necessary to add the following property for proper data 
conversions: "defaultNChar=true"*

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that weblogic driver causes problems as well. Try oracle thin driver `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`.
I think this is part of official WebLogic documentation for some products in the suite,  e.g., for portal http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs100/db/oracle.html#wp1077052